# How to avoid creating nested array when appending new value into an array in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to avoid creating nested array whenever appending new value into an array in react js. Currently, I am reading a data from localstorage which containing string value and localStorage data keep updating the value, so I am trying to store all value from localStorage whenever any change happen but with the below code it's creating nested array . Can you please provide some solution to this ?

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));

useEffect(() => {
setData((data) => [data, storedData])

}, [storedData])
```

Above logic create nested array which I wanted to avoid and wanted to keep appending the string value whatever it's coming from localStorage

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the spread operator,

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));

useEffect(() => {
setData((data) => [...data, storedData])

}, [storedData])
```

Comment: I used that one but got an error like data is not iterable

Comment: using null value in initial render would break it, changed it to an empty array

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, initialize the `data` with an empty array.
Then you can use the [spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get all the values of the "string" stored in array and add the newly fetched string to `data`.
Here's code

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));

useEffect(() => {
setData((data) => [...data, storedData])

}, [storedData])
```

I guess this should work. You can try it